# Error while installing the Minikube in AWS ubuntu 18.04 VM(t3.micro)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, minikube

I am getting below error while installing/configuring conntrack-tools-1.4.6 using command ./configure --prefix=/usr.
I referered below links to install the **minikube**:

**https://www.radishlogic.com/kubernetes/running-minikube-in-aws-ec2-ubuntu/**

I tried setting the environment variable but still the same error.Please help to resolve the issue.

**Error:**
configure: error: in `/conntrack-tools-1.4.6':
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBNFNETLINK_CFLAGS
and LIBNFNETLINK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by lack of memory in Your EC2 instance. The EC2 [`t3.micro`](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/) only has 1GB of memory. Note that the article You are following uses instance that has only 1GB of memory and probably was barely enough for older minikube version.

Currently minikube requires at least 2GB of memory.

According to [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/#what-youll-need):

> ### What you’ll need
>
> - 2GB of free memory
> - 20GB of free disk space
> - Internet connection
> - Container or virtual machine manager, such as:  [Docker](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/),  [Hyperkit](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperkit/),  [Hyper-V](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/),  [KVM](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/kvm2/),  [Parallels](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/parallels/),  [Podman](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/podman/),  [VirtualBox](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/virtualbox/), or  [VMWare](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/vmware/)

I suggest retrying the instructions with additional memory (2gb in total) in Your instance.

Hope it helps.